# get_template_part - how to find html file which is being render

Tags: get-template-part

I am new to Wordpress

I can see following file

```
<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/header/site', 'branding' ); ?>
```

But I am not able to find the file which is being rendered here in right menu of Edit theme section .

Can some one please help me in how to identify files when using a template.

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter of the function is the slug and the second is the string for the file, so you’ll look for the directory `template-parts/header/` and then the file `site-branding`.

Assuming it’s for a theme, you’ll start in the theme directory and look for the `template-parts` directory there.